# How can I solve this BootCamp partition mess I've created?

Tags: bootcamp, imac, partition, setup

[image]

This is my `diskutil` list. I've gotten my new iMac today and everything was going great so I wanted to install windows via bootcamp. After it booted into Windows setup I had problems choosing and formatting the BootCamp partition that was created, so I deleted it and chose new. After this didn't work either I restarted and after several different tries I now have this mess of partitions that I can`t delete via BootCamp Assistant nor Disk Utility.

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve this so I can get to my original FusionDrive disk to try from the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

- Boot to Internet Recovery Mode
- Open Terminal in the menubar > Utilities
- Enter `diskutil list` to get the disk identifiers of your internal SSD (probably disk0), HDD (probably disk1) and the CoreStorage volume (probably disk3 or disk4 - apply the disk identifiers below according to the findings in your environment)
- Now remove the seven partitions on the HDD with gpt:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk disk3 #the device identifier of the CoreStorage volume
  diskutil umountDisk disk1 #the device identifier of the HDD
  diskutil umountDisk disk0 #the device identifier of the SSD
  gpt remove -i 9 disk1 #the device identifier of the HDD
  ```

  Repeat the above steps six times but lower the index number (-i) by one in each step:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk disk3 #the device identifier of the CoreStorage volume
  diskutil umountDisk disk1 #the device identifier of the HDD
  diskutil umountDisk disk0 #the device identifier of the SSD
  gpt remove -i 8 disk1 #the device identifier of the HDD
  ```

  ...

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk disk3 #the device identifier of the CoreStorage volume
  diskutil umountDisk disk1 #the device identifier of the HDD
  diskutil umountDisk disk0 #the device identifier of the SSD
  gpt remove -i 3 disk1 #the device identifier of the HDD
  ```
- Resize the CoreStorage stack:

  ```
  diskutil cs resizeStack lvUUID 2120g
  ```

  with lvUUID: the UUID of your Logical Volume (8DC64131-3881-4971-B870-2FB6BFB58EDB)
- Reboot to your main volume
- Reinstall your current system to recreate your missing RecoveryHD or use this tool [Recovery Partition Creator](http://musings.silvertooth.us/2016/10/recovery-partition-4-0-4/)

---

Instead it should also be possible to merge all partitions (disk1s3-disk1s9) to free space and expand the CS LV then without booting to Internet Recovery Mode (untested):

```
diskutil mergePartitions Free Space disk1s3 disk1s9
```

Then reinstall your current system to recreate your missing RecoveryHD or use this tool [Recovery Partition Creator](http://musings.silvertooth.us/2016/10/recovery-partition-4-0-4/)